# How do I enable locate and queue the database to be built?

Tags: command-line, files, cron, locate

On a new Ubuntu 10.4 instance, I tried to use the `locate` command only to receive the error

```
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

from using this command on other systems I'm guessing that this means the database has not yet been built (it is a fresh install). I believe it is supposed to run daily, but how would I queue it up to run immediately?

Also, how is "run daily" determined? If I have a box that I only turn on for an hour at a time will the database ever be built on it's own?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The cron job is defined in `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`.

To run it immediately:

```
sudo updatedb
```

or better

```
sudo ionice -c3 updatedb
```

This is better because `updatedb` is set in the *Idle I/O scheduling class*, so that it do not disturb (from the I/O point of view) other applications. From `ionice` man page:

> ```
>   -c class
>           The scheduling class. 0 for none, 1 for real time, 2 for 
>           best-effort, 3 for idle.
>
>   ........................
>
>   Idle   A program running with idle io priority will only get disk time
>          when no other  program  has  asked  for disk io for a defined 
>          grace period. The impact of idle io processes on normal system 
>          activity should be zero. This scheduling class does not take a 
>          priority argument. Presently, this scheduling class is permitted 
>          for an ordinary user (since kernel 2.6.25).
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the second one better?

Comment: @cwd: see updated answer.

Comment: This worked for me as well